# CSS make background image overlap container

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how to make an image overlap the container width it is placed in.

So, for example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="background-image"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.container {
max-width: 1170px;
}

.background-image {
background: url(/img/my-image.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
```

So on a 1663px wide screen, the .container class is 1170px wide. The background image is 1170px wide as well.

What I'm trying to achieve, is make the image full-width (overlap the .container class so it's 1663px wide) without adjusting the HTML.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want a part of the image to dissapear when it goes offscreen?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. 
Do you want the image to span the width of screen ?
If so just put it inside another div and set width:100%

Comment: You obviously can’t make a background image wider than the element it is the background of - that’d be like trying to paint a wall, five meters to the side of where the wall ended … Maybe you can adapt the technique shown here, https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/, to make your inner div element “break out” of the parent.

Comment: @HarshPhoujdar Hi, in this case, the html can not be adjusted. The image has to overlap the .container class width.

Comment: @Aurora Why exactly would you even want to do this? What are you trying to achive by doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fixed width of 1663px...

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  background: salmon;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.background-image {
  background: url(https://www.fillmurray.com/800/300) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
  
  /* The important part... */
  width: 1663px;
  max-width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="background-image"></div>
</div>
```

(remove the `max-width: 100vw;` if you don't want the width to adjust with the window)

---

Or if you would rather full width...

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  background: salmon;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.background-image {
  background: url(https://www.fillmurray.com/800/300) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
  
  /* The important part... */
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50vw);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="background-image"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, You need to background image with full width.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  min-height: 500px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: red;
}

.background-image {
  background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif) repeat center center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.6;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="background-image"></div>
  container
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, no this is not what we are after. We want the image to overlap the .container width. The html can not be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for the property `background-size: cover` which will create the desired effect, i have added a code snippet so you can see.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
}

.background-image {
  background: url(/img/my-image.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  /* This will create the effect you are looking for */
  background-color: #000000;
  /* This can be removed, for illustration purposes only*/
  height: 500px;
  /* This can be removed, for illustration purposes only*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="background-image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, that’s not what they are after. The background image is supposed to go over the full viewport width, despite the fact that the element is inside a container element with a limited width.

Comment: Hi, thank you but this doesn't solve it. The backbround image has to overlap the .container width it is currently placed in.